# Android: Detect if night mode is set to FOLLOW_SYSTEM with AppCompatDelegate

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-dark-theme, android-night-mode

I'm trying to make a settings option that allows the user to choose whether the app should be in night mode, day mode or follow the system default. In order to display the current setting to the user I need to get it from the system. However the code I'm using below always returns `MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED`. Am I doing something wrong here?

I have the following code:

```
val x = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()
        when (x) {
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {"testsadflke-  MODE_NIGHT_NO".log()}
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {"testsadflke-  MODE_NIGHT_YES".log()}
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY -> {"testsadflke-  MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY".log()}
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM -> {"testsadflke-  MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM".log()}
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED -> {"testsadflke-  MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED".log()}
        }
```

The log output is:

```
2020-07-01 21:47:08.751 6783-6783/com.example.macrotracker D/(AnyExt.kt:6)log(): Object: testsadflke-  MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED
```

However I think this is incorrect because my appTheme extends the material DayNight theme. Additionally, when I enable or disable night mode, my app changes theme, so it must be following the system mode. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you calling `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode` yourself?

Comment: I call this before calling `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode`. I figure since my app is changing theme based on the device day/night theme, `getDefaultNightMode` should be returning `MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppCompat's night mode support comes at two layers:

- the "default" layer - controlled by `setDefaultNightMode()`, read via `getDefaultNightMode()`
- the "local" layer - controlled by `setLocalNightMode()`, read via `getLocalNightMode()`

The "default" layer only applies if you have not set a local mode (i.e., `getLocalNightMode()` returns `MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED`) by explicitly calling `setLocalNightMode()` with a different value.

For a similar reason, if you've never called `setDefaultNightMode()`, then `getDefaultNightMode()` is expected to return `MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED` - unspecified means that you haven't set it to any particular value.

It is important to note that `AppCompatDelegate` does not persist any value you set - you need to call `setDefaultNightMode()` every time your application is created (i.e., to restore whatever value you want / have previous saved yourself after process death) and `setLocalNightMode()` (if you use that on a particular Activity/Dialog) when that component is created.

As per the [`MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate#MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED):

> If both the default and local night modes are set to this value [`MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED`], then the default value of `MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM` is applied.

Therefore if you're not using the local mode at all, then you can treat `MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED` the same as `MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM` as that is exactly what AppCompat does in the case where both are `MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED`.

Comment: Oh I see, but what is the difference between `local` and `default`? Is `default` set by the device (like in the device night mode setting)? Does `local` only apply to your app?

Comment: They both are only for your app. The default mode for your app applies anytime a local mode is not set - hence why it is called the default mode. Think of default as an option that applies to every activity and every dialog in your app and local as an option you set on a specific activity or specific dialog to force it to a particular mode.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clarifying that. So to build on this question does calling `setDefaultlNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED)` set Android 10+ devices to `MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM` and Android 9- devices to `MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY`? And if that is the case, does that mean using `.._UNSPECIFIED` is the best/most convenient way to make the app follow the device night mode setting regardless of android version?

Comment: As per the documentation I specifically quoted, if both the default and local mode are `UNSPECIFIED`, it uses `FOLLOW_SYSTEM`. That is true for every API level. It will never use `AUTO_BATTERY` unless you specifically set the mode to `AUTO_BATTERY`. You might consider [reading the guidance on Night mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#changing_themes_in-app), which specifically calls out how you should be handling night mode across API levels.